# Vue parent's data not updating child's prop

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue parent component that has on the data section a counter, like this:

```
data() {
    return {
      count: 0,
    }
```

And I pass it to a child component as a prop

```
///on parent component
<child 
      :counter="count"
    />
/// on child component
export default {
  props: {
  counter: { type: Number, required: true },
}
```

But when I update the parent's count (adding 1), the child's counter doesn't change, is still 0.

This is the child template:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex w-80 flex-col">
    {{ counter }}
  </div>
```

And the only error I get on console is: [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function. But is found in other vue component, so I dont think that is the cause.

I'm new in Vue, so any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you have any error in console?

Comment: Can you show the template of the child component?

Comment: it should wor there must be something wrong in template, please log your console  error